# Bootstrap dropdown button at the bottom of a collapse panel z-index issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a bootstrap dropdown button at the bottom of a collapse panel however there appears to be a z-index issue when using the dropdown at the bottom of a panel.

I created an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/6SFcp/1/) showing the issue.

```
          <br>
          <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have not added any custom code to the example (apart from my attempt at changing the zindex of the dropdownlist)
Everything has been copied directly from the bootstrap site.

Is this a bug within bootstrap? can anyone suggest what element i need to modify to allow the dropdown to appear above the panel?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the `overflow: hidden` on the `.panel` class that is hiding the `.dropdown-menu`. You can override it...

```
.panel-group .panel{
     overflow: visible;
}
```